# Change the polymorphic type column value when doing lookups in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism

I have a table called comments

```
class Comments
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

and a class called Post

```
class Post
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

the problem is that I recently name spaced the post table. Now it's:

```
class Nytimes::Post
   has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

I worry that from here on out that when I do `Nytimes::Post.first.comments`, it will look for rows in the comments database that have the `commentable_type` set to `Nytimes::Post`. Is there any way to override this to look for comments with a commentable_type of `Post` instead?

I already took care of the writes. I am writing all new comments into the database with `commentable_type: "Post"`. However, it's the retrieval that I'm worried about.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Please check out my below answer, hope it would work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override default behaviour of polymorphic association using below:

```
class Nytimes::Post
   # has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_many :comments, ->(s) { where(comments: { commentable_type: s.class }) }, foreign_key: :commentable_id
end
```

And even if your child class is also have namespace i.e. "class Nytimes::Comments" then you could use like below:

```
has_many :comments, ->(s) { where(comments: { commentable_type: s.class }) }, foreign_key: :commentable_id, class_name: 'Nytimes::Comments'
```